# Fisher's 3x2 Post-Hoc

Tags: post-hoc, fishers-exact-test

Good evening,

I ran a Fisher's 3X2 Table for a Variable Happiness (Measured High, Medium and Low) and another variable measured Yes/No. This yielded statistical significance.

I was wondering if there was a post-hoc test which could be performed. I had two thoughts:

1. Running 3 Fisher's 2x2 Tests with High-Medium, Medium-Low and High-Low and then applying Bonferonni Correction to significance (0.05/3)
2. Running 3 Fisher's 2x2 Tests with High vs Non-High, Medium vs Non-Medium and Low vs Non-Low and then applying Bonferonni Correction to significance (0.05/3)

Would either method be valid/are any of the methods invalid?

Thank you so much in advance for any replies, have been struggling with this dilemma for days and there are no references in the literature.